# Cоздания потоков и параметры функции

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток, начал учить потоки в плюсах. Элементарщину научился делать, но тут вопрос, как на примере кода сделать, чтобы функция печатала строчку задаваемое количество раз?

```
DWORD WINAPI Func1 (void * param,int size) // сайз
{
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    cout << "SWAG" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
// main
HANDLE thread1=CreateThread(0,0,Func1,0,0,0); // как сюда кинуть параметр?
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы документацию читали?

У функции, вызываемой из `CreateThread` д.б. **один параметр**.

Так что, сделайте структуру (лучше выделять под нее память malloc-ом), заполните нужными параметрами и передайте ее адрес.

Comment: @petruska, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Смотрите.

Во-первых, лучше всего перейти на свежую версию компилятора и использовать универсальный `std::thread` и прогрессивные лямбды вместо платформо-специфического WinAPI:

```
#include <thread>

std::thread t([size]()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << "SWAG" << std::endl;
});
```

(Кстати, использовать консольный вывод из разных потоков — [не самая лучшая идея](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141008-00/?p=43893).)

Если хотите всё же использовать WinAPI, вам придётся передавать параметр нетипизированным способом — через `void*`-параметр. Для этого вам придётся выделить нужные данные (параметр) в heap-памяти, передать указатель на них в `ThreadProc`, там закастить в нужный тип и применить. Не забудьте уничтожить выделенные данные.